# Bread alternatives with lentils

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread, legumes

Due to an intolerance to wheat, I have recently been testing out different recipes to make bread without wheat or yeast. One option I have tried a couple of times is using lentils instead of wheat. However, every time I have tried so far I get the same "problem": the end result is very crumbly, and falls apart too easy.

Usually, to make this bread, I grind the dry lentils in a food processor, then add it to the other ingredients and mix before throwing into the oven. I recently saw a recipe for lentil tortillas that soaks the lentils before grinding them. I'm trying this next, though it did not provide specific instructions.

Here's my question:
Is there a specific method to follow while soaking the lentils to make a bread (or tortilla) stick better or be more fluffy?
Any additional suggestions would be appreciated too.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm curious why you don't use established techniques for this? Masa Harina springs to mind for authentic tortilla. Channa flour (chickpea) works well for these sorts of things. There are also many types of gluten free flours available now (I suppose this depends on where you are in the world), and tons of recipes by simply searching "gluten free yeast free bread", which will provide lots of good options.

Comment: I've tried a few other recipes I found online, but most I did not like for one reason or another (e.g. ingredients I don't use often and don't store for long, or ingredients that are expensive or that I am also allergic to). However, I had not considered chickpea flour. I will look into that one. Thanks for the suggestion 

Comment: Not bread, per se, but in making felafel with various types of beans, soaking before grinding is normal, and soaking and grinding uncooked beans, then cooking the felafel requires no other binder, while using cooked beans as some other recipes do requires an additional binder... Other than "won't rise the same" being intolerant of wheat does not automatically mean you can't use yeast, if you want to...

Comment: I made some rather nice gram flour (chickpea) chapatis once.  But they were very much better eaten freshly made, not even reheating very well. But that was just one recipe

Answer (score 1):

There is a tortilla-like product that’s made from lentils, but you also add rice: dosa

Sohla El-Waylly explained the process  in a video during the pandemic, and I’ve successfully used that process (mix it up, let it ferment, cook on a griddle):  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7eV1ZgwB9bY